# Как переименовать папку users, если нет функции переименовать?

Tags: windows

Не могу переименовать папку users(sania). При нажатии правой кнопки нету в списке текста Переименовать. Испробовал множество вариантов.

Comment: Никак. Это не название папки, а имя пользователя.

Comment: Я понял вас. Попытался переименовать имя пользователя sania, но никак не получается.

Comment: Насколько я знаю при создании аккаунта Windows создает папку в системном каталоге с именем этого аккаунта. И имя этой папки такая же константа, как например путь в котором установлена ОС.

Comment: Зачем вообще менять users на sania?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а какой ответ вы ожидаете?) [Примерно такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTbYP.jpg)?

Comment: @eccs0103  хз) мне интересно что движет людьми делать то, что они не понимают)

Comment: Даже если переименовать пользователя, имя системной папки пользователя не изменится. Единственный способ переименовать её - переустановить ОС.

Comment: Добавить нового пользователя, зайти в него , удалить старого.